# How do I use variables and non-variables in a single sed command?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, sed, text-processing

I'm trying to use `sed` to replace some PHP lines.

My problem is I want to replace a line with PHP variables with a string including a Bash variable.

Here is an example:

```bsh
sudo sed -i 's/$sUrl . $this_sOutDir/https:\/\/'$bucketname'.s3.amazonaws.com . $this->_sOutDir/g' /var/www/html/$name/core/oxconfig.php
```

As you can see, I want to replace `$sUrl . $this->_sOutDir` (literally) with the s3 URL, which includes a Bash variable. I'm trying to use double quotes but it's not working for me:

```bsh
 sudo sed -i 's/$sUrl . $this_sOutDir/https:\/\/"$bucketname".s3.amazonaws.com . $this->_sOutDir/g' /var/www/html/$name/core/oxconfig.php
```

I'm also trying to use the complete `s/...` in double quotes but it's not working because `sed` thinks that the first variables are also Bash variables.

The result is:

```
return https://.s3.amazonaws.com . $this->_sOutDir . '/';
```

Comment: Your example works alright for me : http://paste.ubuntu.com/15696070/  Does `bucketname` contain anyting special ? is it being set ? Is it a variable with specific scope ? is it used in a function or so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go two different ways:

1. Using single quotes: break out of the single quotes and reference the variable (using double quotes to prevent word splitting and filename expansion):

   ```bsh
   sudo sed -i 's/$sUrl . $this_sOutDir/https:\/\/'"$bucketname"'.s3.amazonaws.com . $this->_sOutDir/g' /var/www/html/$name/core/oxconfig.php
   ```
2. Using double quotes: escape the `$` characters to be treated literally:

   ```bsh
   sudo sed -i "s/\$sUrl . \$this_sOutDir/https:\/\/$bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com . \$this->_sOutDir/g' /var/www/html/$name/core/oxconfig.php
   ```

*However*, the caveat is: if `$bucketname` contains `sed` special characters / sequences, the `sed` command will break (in this case since the variable is to be expanded in the replacement section, the concern is about it possibly containing the separator, accidental backreferences or `&`.

One way to go around this is [sanitazing the variable beforehand by escaping possible separators, accidental backreferences and `&` characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2705678/4316166) to prevent them from being interpreted as such.

Another way is using Perl instead of `sed`, passing the variable directly to Perl which will handle special characters at replacement time (`$` characters to be treated literally must be escaped even if using single quotes with this method):

```bsh
sudo perl -i -spe 's/\$sUrl . \$this_sOutDir/https:\/\/$bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com . \$this->_sOutDir/g' -- -bucketname="$bucketname"
```

```bsh
$ echo '$sUrl . $this_sOutDir' | perl -spe 's/\$sUrl . \$this_sOutDir/https:\/\/$bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com . \$this->_sOutDir/g' -- -bucketname="string/with/separators/&/and/accidental\$1backreferences"
https://string/with/separators/&/and/accidental$1backreferences.s3.amazonaws.com . $this->_sOutDir
```